# How to remove Tilde(~) from the string using regEx in jquery

Tags: javascript

I have a string `"#2723 LAURA BAUGH~~MELBOURNE~FL~32935~US"` with delimter Tilde(~),
Could you please help me with regex to remove ~ using jquery.?

I tried this regex: `replace(/(\~~,)/g, " ")` but that doesn't worked.

your inputs are helps me a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have a string "#2723 LAURA BAUGH~~MELBOURNE~FL~32935~US" with delimter Tilde(~), ... remove ~ using jquery?

jQuery is not necessary, the `.replace` function is an extension of the String interface. You can use `String.replace(/~/g, ' ')`

```
console.log("#2723 LAURA BAUGH~~MELBOURNE~FL~32935~US".replace(/~/g, ' '));
```

Comment: Thank you so much for answer @humble.rumble,
I need the string to be seperated with space , Sample String: **2723 LAURA BAUGH MELBOURNE FL 32935 US**.
Can you please help?

Comment: And why `~` is a "special" character? Just because it looks funny? ;-D